# set form autocomplete off in codeigniter global

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In My codeigniter module. I have around 75 pages with forms, I need to add an auto complete attributes globally. For example, I set the autocomplete off attribute on my view pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you will need to use jQuery to do this in less complex manner.

You can use this code:

`$('form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');`

It will assign autocomplete attribute to all the forms.